# ¿Porque no funciona la class conectar?

Tags: php

Tengo este codigo copiado de un ejemplo para crear una clase conexion para un modelo vista controlador, el problema es que el codigo salta un error de "undefined method 'get_mkessage'" que se supone que el error no deberia saltar ya que el codigo esta copiado perfecto y en el ejemplo funciona.

Aqui el codigo.

```
<?php
class Conectar{
    public static function conexion(){
        try{
            $conexion = new mysqli("localhost","root","","practica");
        }catch(Exception $e){
            die('Error:'.$e->get_message());
        }
        return $conexion;
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El error que te devuelve te está indicando que get_message no existe, dado que no ha sido definido por ti previamente.

Sustituye **get_message** por **getMessage()**.

```
<?php
class Conectar{
    public static function conexion(){
        try{
            $conexion = new mysqli("localhost","root","","practica");
        }catch(Exception $e){
            die('Error:'.$e->getMessage());
        }
        return $conexion;
    }
}
?>
```

En la siguiente dirección te dejo el uso de getMessage: https://www.php.net/manual/es/exception.getmessage.php